# Remove block with Javascript without "hidden" css styles

Tags: javascript, cookies, html, hidden

I have a problem - I want to DELETE the div's rather than just hide them with css on my web page. I'm newbie in Javascript and I can not say for sure whether this is but I think that should be used function `removeChild()`. Here's the script:

http://jsbin.com/ufoyor/edit#javascript,html/

It works like this:

1) "X" button hide `pronto` and `crossClose` divs due to the fact-purpose style of "hidden" these blocks.

2) The script sets a specific value in a cookie if the value matched the block is not shown (with style = "visibility: hidden;").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can remove the element together with its subtree with removeChild().

However, for I suggest setting style `display: none`. It won't display at all (won't occupy the space as `visibility:hidden` does).

Comment: Excellent! How could I forget about it

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript use `removeChild()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild
In jQuery you have method `remove()`: http://api.jquery.com/remove/